# Localizing HTML files / Parallel file editing

Tags: localization, editor, text-editor

Due to timing constrains, I have developed a web application where a lot of **language-specific strings have been directly hard-coded** to large HTML/Javascript static files. Due to poor coding, code and content have not been properly separated.

To achieve **quick and dirty localization**, I am looking for some kind of text editor that would allow to "tag" the local elements of a file and turn them into "custom fields". These fields could then be stored in some resource file and translated independently from the shared structure, to generate multiple localized versions of  the file.

I realize that I could do this myself through a "simple" templating mechanism, for instance by keeping a shared root file containing fields like **{%welcome_message%}** and a csv file for field translations, and then generate localized files.

But is there a **text editor** that could do this in a fast, user-friendly way ? For instance where we could see/modify the custom field values (as well as the root parts) directly when editing a file ?

What would be great for instance, would a a text editor feature/plugin allowing some kind of **parallel file editing** by distinguishing "root" and "localized" parts in a set of files.

(Note : currently I am using diff/merge tools to achieve this kind of results, but it will become increasingly cumbersome as we add more languages).

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help you in parallel file editing http://www.sublimetext.com/.

Comment: Thanks Hemesh, this is a great editor. But it seems that Sublime Text's parallel editing refers to multiple selections within a file, and not across multiple files.
My need is really different, and I haven't been able to find a plugin that answers it... Seems I'll have to code one myself :-/